# Query result output to csv file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using the following query to save all the result in .CSV file returned by SQL query.

```
EXEC  master..xp_cmdshell 'SQLCMD -S . -E -Q "SELECT TOP 10
    customercode, customername, businessdescription, ctypecode
FROM ArchivalDB.dbo.customer" -s"," -b -o d:\data\myoutput1.csv', no_output
```

It works but, if any of my column contact ',' than the output of csv file gets disturbed.

I know that has to do something with the `-s` parameter.

Can anyone please help me in this matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok removing `comma` with space or any other delimiter, then change your sql query to

```
SELECT TOP 10
    replace(customercode,',',' '), 
    replace(customername,',',' '), 
    replace(businessdescription,',',' '), 
    replace(ctypecode,',',' ')
FROM ArchivalDB.dbo.customer
```

Comment: This way I will have to alter all my saved queries. is there any other way of   achieving the same result ?

Comment: You can choose another delimiter (like `~` or `|` etc) , and use that in `-s`. Once file is created, replace `comma` with space or any other value and then replace your delimiter with `comma`. But it will be an overhead on existing process and more time consuming.